# How to specialize for template template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to specialize a function using a templated type but I am having trouble getting the desired results.

Consider the following simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>


template <typename T>
void foo(){
    std::cout << "In foo1 with type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template< template<class, class...> class VEC, typename T>
void foo(){
    std::cout << "In foo2 with vec type: " << typeid(VEC<T>).name()
              << " and template type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    foo<int>();
    foo<std::vector, int>();
    foo<std::vector<int>>(); // Would like this to call the second version of foo
}
```

The output of which is

```
In foo1 with type: i
In foo2 with vec type: St6vectorIiSaIiEE and template type: i
In foo1 with type: St6vectorIiSaIiEE
```

Is there a way to write a template signature for the second version of foo that would be used for the last invocation of foo (with the std::vector template parameter)?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like: `template<>
void foo<std::vector<int>>(){
    std::cout << "In specialized foo1 with vec type: " << typeid(VEC<int>).name()
              << " and template type: " << typeid(int).name() << std::endl;
}` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I want something more general than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot specialize function templates partially, the usual approach is to use a helper class template:

```
template <typename T> struct X
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "Primary\n"; }
};

template <template <typename...> class Tmpl, typename T>
struct X<Tmpl<T>>
{
    static void f() { std::cout << "Specialized\n"; }
};

template <typename T> void foo() { X<T>::f(); }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @acorso: No problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is tag dispatching:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

template <typename T> void foo(Tag<T>) { std::cout << "generic\n"; }

template <typename T> void foo(Tag<std::vector<T>>) { std::cout << "vector\n"; }


template <typename T> void foo()
{
    foo(Tag<T>{});
}
```